# Form for child born in UK to Tier 2 parents

Tags: uk-visa

I am on a Tier 2 (General ) visa and my daughter was born in May 2018 in UK. I tried to obtain a Tier 2 dependant child visa for her using the form https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/pbs-dependant-child . But the form does not provide the option to choose the length of visa for my daughter ( less than 3 years or more than 3 years). It asks for my CoS length ( which was 5 years) and assumes that my daughter should also get a 5 year visa ( more than 3 year category). I have 2 years to go before I can apply for ILR. So a 3 year visa for my daughter would be sufficient. Please let me know the correct form to use and applicable fee in this circumstance.

Comment: What is 'MY ILR'? Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

> But the form does not provide the option to choose the length of visa for my daughter ( less than 3 years or more than 3 years).

This is entirely at the discretion of the UK government, not the person applying.

> It asks for my CoS length ( which was 5 years) and assumes that my daughter should also get a 5 year visa ( more than 3 year category).

It 'assumes' nothing. The Home Office will take a look at the application along with the supporting evidence and make decision on her visa based on that. Any dependent is naturally and logically connected to the visa status of their main supporter. Since you are Tier 2 general, her dependent visa will reflect that.

You are using the correct form in this case.

**Note**: If you have no plans to leave the country with your child in the next 2 years before acquiring ILR, she doesn't need a visa to remain in the country legally.

Comment: There are probably going to be some very disappointed grandparents (and aunts and uncles) if they have to wait until the OP has ILR

Comment: @MartinBonner, Sorry a bit confused. Disappointed relatives? Are you referring to the fact that the child doesn't need a visa to remain in the United Kingdom? That was just a side point. Obviously if they need (or want) to travel, the child can get a dependent visa right now. No need to wait until the OP has ILR.